# hide label in django admin fieldset readonly field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a really annoying issue that I can't hide a label in the admin if the field is readonly:

```
class Observable(Model):
    constraints=ManyToManyField('Constraint')

class ObservableAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin):

    form=ObservableAdminForm
    fieldsets =[('other fields',{}),
                ('All Constraints...:', {'fields':('constraints',)}),] 
    readonly_fields = ['constraints'] # I want to hide the "Constraints: " label

class ObservableAdminForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    model=Observable
    fields=('parent', 'name', 'alias', 'comments', 'constraints')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       # CAN'T DO self.fields['constraints'].label=''
```

The problem is that readonly field defined in the admin don't show up in the modelform fields at all.

The django admin correctly displays the constraints as a comma separated block of text, but it shows the "Constraints" label which is redundant with "All Constraints..." in the fieldset. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

thanks,
Danny

Comment: I also want this feature; why django team didn't add style class...

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a truly ugly workaround that does what I want...

I hacked fieldset.html to include the following:

```
{% if field.label_tag != "<label>Constraints:</label>" %}
  {{ field.label_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

So that the fieldset label tag doesn't appear for the the Constraints field but is otherwise unaffected.

Don't try this at home...

Answer (score 1):

sure, Override the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html` is your first choice, you can complete and flexible control over page elements.

but if it's not convenient to modify html files. you can use Monkey Patching to change the readonly field `label_tag` function to control what html tags return.

In addition,what I'm not quite sure about is you want hide fieldset title or field label ?  because Davide Brunato's answer is hide fieldset's title.

my solution is Override `AdminReadonlyField.label_tag`

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.helpers import AdminReadonlyField

old_label_tag = AdminReadonlyField.label_tag

def label_tag(self):
    hide_label = ['Constraint']
    if self.field['name'] in hide_label:
        return format_html('')
    else:
        return old_label_tag(self)

AdminReadonlyField.label_tag = label_tag
```

Answer (score 0):

The admin form is created dynamically from a metaclass when add_view or change_view are called (see `adminForm` variable in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`).

So the simplest workaround is to put `None` into the fieldset's label:

```
class ObservableAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin):

    form=ObservableAdminForm
    fieldsets =[('other fields',{}),
                (None, {'fields':('constraints',)}),] 
    readonly_fields = ['constraints'] # I want to hide the "Constraints: " label
```

Alternatively you can set an empty label using the attribute `verbose_name` in the model's field declaration:

```
class Observable(Model):
    constraints=ManyToManyField('Constraint', verbose_name='')
```

but you cannot eliminate the label suffix (':') because is fixed in the code (`django/contrib/admin/helpers.py`).

I prefer the first solution when is feasible (an appropriate label is needed for the fieldset if you want to hide it with `collapse`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't believe either of these responses works for me. The first method hides the fieldset label but still shows the "constraints: " label for the field. The is exactly backwards from what I want, which is to hide the "constraints: " label and show the fieldset label.

The second solution does what I want, except for the ":" as you mention, but the problem here is that I need constraints in other forms. I guess I could change the label in all those, so that might work after all.